# Remember Original Input if the input is invalid

Tags: php, sql, forms, session, cookies

*Hi there!*

I have a login form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
  Username:
    <p><input type="text" name="id" /></p>
  Password:
    <p><input type="password" name="pass" /></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="login" />
   <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

and the validation is in login.php aswell, a single file validation).

If the email or password doesn't match the error message appears below the form. If the input is valid, it redirects to homepage.php (header ("location: homepage.php");)

What I want to do is: ***if the password is wrong, or doesn't match with the username, it displays the form again with the original username input.***

Is it by using cookie?
If anyone has any suggestion, please let me know.

Sankyu :)

Comment: you can do it by saving post data into sessions or using iframe and making your form target to iframe...

Comment: @user790454 thank you. it works now. ive tried using value="<?php echo isset($_POST['formName'])?$_POST['formName']:""; ?>" thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the old value inside the session variable (**$_SESSION**) and displaying it on the value property of the element.